# default CSS media types "screen" vs "print" vs "default"

Tags: css, media

In the face of endless responsive size discussions like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)
```

it appears that the concept of a "default" CSS file has disappeared?

Is it the case that ALL best practices assume the big three "screen," "print," and "ie" are all that are needed?

Is it the case that settings listed under "screen" are also available under "print?" Or is that still most properly covered by a "default" css sheet included with no "media" attribute?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `@media print` or `@media only screen` you use scope operators to make only that section relevant to the `@` reference.

for example:

```
@media print {

h3 {display: none;
}

img {display: none;
}

body {margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 80%;   
}

#wrapper {box-shadow:   none;
}

.floatRight {float: right;
}

.clearFloat {clear: both;
}

.centerText {text-align: center;
}

li {padding-bottom: 10px;
}

}
```

will all only be called when the user selects print.

Any code outside of the scope (`{}`) will be considered regular css and apply to every page that it is linked to.

**UPDATE:**

The 3 main `@` labels should be used only for formatting for those different properties like "printing a page" or "the screen size changing for mobile". You will always have a "default" css page.

Hope this answers your question

Comment: My question is not really about how it works; but rather whether anyone still considers it a best practice. When one google's "css screen print default" or some variation, one finds no references to the default sheet at all. When compass is used to generate a new project, it only creates screen.scss, print.scss and ie.scss. Does anyone still use the default sheet? Or think it's a good idea?

Comment: I just finished taking a css course in June and I was taught that you will always have a default css page. Compass is just doing that to make things easier for you by not having to type out those extra pages. You should create an extra page called "default.css" so every area is covered.

Comment: That's the way I'm going with it. However, (and I know this really is a compass question) if one runs "compass create --using blueprint" the resultant screen.scss has all the code one would normally expect to find in the default file. I guess I'm beating a dead horse. Thank you for your time.

Comment: That is because the screen.scss (being used for mobile) will more than likely use the same styles as the default css page and no problem